# How to increase the maximum blocks for `getPastEvent` method for web3?

Tags: web3js

I'm trying to get the past events from a contract's `Deposit` method:

```
const events = await tornado.getPastEvents('Deposit', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest' })
```

However, web3 throws an error saying it's too many blocks:

```
Error: Error: Returned error: requested too many blocks from 90000 to 97491, maximum is set to 512
```

How can I increase the max of 512 blocks?

Comment: How do you connect to the ethereum network? infura, geth, parity.

Comment: I'm actually connecting to the Avalanche testnet (Fuji): https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc

Comment: It seems to be a limitation by the api provider, geth doesn't have such problem.

Comment: That makes sense then, thank you.